# How to fetch the complete response and response headers from the network tab using Karate UI?

Tags: karate

I am testing a website application. But to start the testing, need to add two parameters to the website URL which comes from a different URL. And the URL which provides the two parameters is an API endpoint URl but not accessible from Postman or any other third party tool as this endpoint url is an internal part of a third party. But we can access this endpoint URL using the Chrome Browser for which I need to fetch the response of that URL and store it in a variable after which I can use the data of that response to make the website work.

Please suggest some piece of code using Karate UI through which I can automate this whole process.